# Android: Layout views of the same size evenly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to layout a set of horizontal and vertical buttons. The problem is that if I indicate 'layout_weight' for buttons, their dimensions don't follow the 'layout_width' & 'layout_height' tags.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve

[image: Valid XHTML]

So, buttons must have identical height & width and distribute evenly horizontally and vertically.

Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Thanks

UPDATE: After a lot of investigation and trying out different solutions, I came to a conclusion that my only option is to create my own custom layout and place buttons correctly there.

Comment: Have a linear layout with orientation = vertical, this can have your vertical buttons in. Set the width of this layout using layout_weight, then the buttons inside it use layout_width="fill_parent".

Do the same for the horizontal buttons in a horizontal layout.

Answer (score 0):

That configuration (the L shape) might make this a tad trickier... since the corner button might size like it's horizontal counterparts or it's vertical counterparts, depending on which linear layout they are apart of. In any event, you should be using wrap_content for the height or width, and they should all have a weight of 1. It's my understanding that the wrap_content for the height or width is important for the Linear Layout to size them correctly. It might work with fill_parent when the weights are all 1, but if you use different weights on different Views with fill_parent, things won't appear as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make it work with linearlayout and weights (which you should be able to do), you could always try to do some manual workarounds using relativelayout.

Comment: Working with different screen sizes... I think it would be impossible with a relative layout...

Comment: I'm not going to say I've tried it, but you might have a point :p though commands like centerInParent works nice for different screens. Maybe he'll find a mix of commands like that that makes it work. But I guess you'd have to embed linearlayouts within the relative one anyway eventually..

Comment: Yea, I didn't mean to say "impossible", lol... that's not a good word. But anyway, right... to get the system to resize all the views to be the same size... there would have to be a LinearLayout in there somewhere.